# не получается установить PWA по клику на кнопку

Tags: reactjs, pwa

У меня приложение на React. 
Моя задача - реализовать установку PWA приложения по клику на кнопку. 
Проблема - не срабатывает событие beforeinstallprompt.
При этом, когда я перехожу в меню браузера и выбираю "добавить на рабочей стол" - приложение устанавливается.

Буду благодарен любым идеям.

код:

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    const styles = {
      width:'100px',
      height:'50px',
      textAlign: 'center',
      position: 'absolute',
      top:0,
      left:0,
      transform: 'translate(50%,50%)'
   };

   const Test = () => {
    const [supportsPWA, setSupportsPWA] = useState(false);
    const [promptInstall, setPromptInstall] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
            console.log('in use')// выводит в консоль
        const handler = e => {
            console.log('in handler') // не выводит в консоль
            e.preventDefault();
            setSupportsPWA(true);
            setPromptInstall(e);
        };
        window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", handler);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("transitionend", handler);
        }, []);
        const onClick = e => {
            alert('click')
            e.preventDefault();
            if (promptInstall) {
                promptInstall.prompt();
            }else{
                    return;
            };
        };

        return (
            supportsPWA && (<button style={styles} onClick={(e) => onClick(e)}>Install</button>)       
        )
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: Первым делом нужно убедиться, что браузер поддерживает этот эвент: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent

Comment: я использую chrome _ он поддерживает

Answer (score 0):

проблема решена, у меня был еще один слушатель beforeinstallprompt